# Magento URLs redirecting to no-route

Tags: magento-1.6, redirect

I have magento setup (Magento ver. 1.6.0.0) on my hosting server and I am trying to build a new php page which has got nothing to do with Magento.

page.php:

```
<?php

echo 'test';

?>
```

I've put this php page in a test folder and tried to access it :

domain.com/test/page.php

But it automatically redirects the page to no-route.

Is there some global setting / config that does this in Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was to do with .htaccess file redirecting to the wrong location and thus the entire URL was always breaking.